# Problem in converting math in Latex to epub using pandoc

Tags: latex, pandoc

Latex code in my tex file:

$\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}$ $=$  $\dot{P}_i$, $\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_i} =\dot{q}_i$

I have given the following command in terminal

pandoc -s science.tex -o science.epub

pandoc is not converting the certain math codes.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

EPUB doesn't have any general way of displaying latex math.  The EPUB3 standard includes MathML, but few readers support this yet.  You can try adding `-t epub3` to your command line to get an EPUB3 document.  You could also try using the `--webtex` option, which will use a web service to convert the tex to an image.